# Figure and table in the same line

Tags: latex

Is there a way to combine tables and figures in the same line? An example could be:

[image]

I know that `\subfigure` and `\subtable` exist, but is there a way to use both of them simultaneously?
I mean, I could always take a screenshot of the table and use \subfigure, but I was looking for something more professional.

Comment: You could use `minipage`s to place your elements besides each other

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre] so we don't have to start from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're finding confusing here is that a `figure` environment can only contain an image (like `\includegraphics`) and a `table` environment can only contain a `tabular`. This is not true. `figure`s and `table`s are just floating constructions and can contain anything (`tabular` inside `figure` or `\includegraphics` inside `table`).

The trick is to set two different caption types inside the same float. Here `\captionof{<type>}{<caption>}` from the [`caption` package](//ctan.org/pkg/caption) and some `minipage`s can help.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
    \captionof{figure}{Figure caption}% \caption{Figure caption}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c} }
      A & b & C & d & e \\
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Table caption}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Since the above construction is set inside a `figure`, using `\caption{Figure caption}` would also be sufficient to set the caption for the image.